# Firebase-Unity Project: Exporting for iOS on Windows 10. Workaround?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Recently added Firebase Storage and Authentication to my Unity project. I work on Windows, have a single Unity Pro License, and want to export my App for iOS, as I have done many times before in this dev process.

However, since the addition of Firebase, I'm told I apparently can't export my Firebase-Enabled Unity project for iOS without swapping Unity to an OSX device (which I don't have in comparable quality).

I've noticed a singular thread here where a supposed workaround was discussed, but can't seem to pull it off myself:

> "The plugin that comes with firebase depends on cocoapods to handle
>   transient dependencies. If you look at the Assets ->
>   PlayServicesResolver -> IOSResolver -> Settings
>
> You can configure it to generate the podfile but not do the remaining
>   steps." - from user johnb003, March 18th 2017.

Can't seem to find the configuration settings described here. Scoured the forums/communities for solutions, but no results elsewhere.

So, that said, any other Firebase user have a workaround for this issue? I adore the collective Google has put together with their product, but I can't really afford to invest in another Unity Pro License just for the sake of working off of my sub-standard Macbook. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a Google Github project, [Unity JAR resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver), describing how the Unity Play Services Resolver works for each target platform.

The documentation is pretty extensive, and solutions are use-case specific, so I can't give you much help on specific podfile settings, but hopefully you can sift through it yourself.